# How to publish NopCommerce and NopCommerce admin website?

Tags: nopcommerce

I have deployed NopCommerce to Windows azure website and I am able to see home page of NopCommerce website on website URL. After I login using admin credentials, I can see Administration link at the top. But when I click on the link, administration website is not shown.

It seems that with NopCommerce admin website does not get deployed. When I tried to publish from Admin website in Visual Studio to azure website, it didn't work. Can someone point me that how can I deploy admin website?

Answer (score 4):

Run Deploy.bat in your root folder.  This will create the entire website structure in the Deployable folder.  FTP that up to your site.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite tricky but will make sense to you after getting used to NopCommerce.

You need to create a subdirectory called 'Administration' and deploy there. Then you copy ALL the files that are inside `/Administration/bin` to `/bin`. These files will include `Nop.Admin.dll` and other dlls used by Admin.

Don't forget to copy all plugin DLLs to `/plugins`

Answer (score 3):

If you add Nop.Admin project reference to Nop.Web it will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Just move **Nop.Admin.dll**  to folder **Nop.web\bin**, this error is due to missing *DLL* **Nop.Admin.dll** from stuff.

Answer (score 2):

For Publishing the NopCommerce Application website below is the step:

Step : 1 - Publish the Nop.Web project.

Step : 2 - Publish the Nop.Admin project.

Go to the publish folder where your publish created

```
Here is your answer below (Step :3   is your answer) :
```

**Step : 3 - Cut all dll from the Administration and Paste all dll to bin folder which in main bin folder for whole project.**

Step : 4 - Copy two things from your source project and in App_Data folder Settings.txt and InstalledPlugins.txt which is not published in your publish file so paste this two files in your publish folder in App_Data. (You need to change the connection string in Setting.txt as per your database host).

Step : 5 - Now you need to copy whole plugins folder from your source folder (but remember this plugins folder you need to copy from the Presentation folder not from the main source where the solution file are there.)and replace it to with your publish's plugin folder.

Step : 6 - Now your publish have been ready.(now you can deploy on hosting server)

Answer (score 1):

If you're using web deploy via Visual Studio, make sure in your publishing settings you deploy as "RELEASE", else the admin directory will 404.  Just thought I'd share after discovering this in version 3.30 myself...

Answer (score 1):

You need to go to the properties of the Nop.Web project and go to the "Package/Publish Web" tab and under the "Items to deploy" set it to "All files in this project folder".

You need to do this for each "Configuration" you have that you deploy under as it will not set it as this on default for any new configurations you might have created.

The reason for needing this is because the admin project is outside of the Nop.Web scope. So the default setting of "Only files needed to run this application" only includes the Nop.Web files. If you select the "All files in this project folder", it will include the admin project because nop.web has references to it.

Hope this helps.