# HOWTO: Deploy NopCommerce from Team Foundation Service to Azure

Tags: azure, msbuild, tfsbuild, nopcommerce

I am currently trying to setup a website based on NopCommerce and since I want to customize it I use the source code and control the build process. My setup is based on Team Foundation Service Builds and deploys to an Azure website.

My problem is that NopCommerce uses a custom MSBuild process that does many file operations to create a deploy-able folder and while this can be run (My build definition is configured to run the custom project that does this), it does not seem to be able to deploy to Azure and I think it's because it does not create the output folder where TFS expects it.

Has anyone solved this problem? I have found another similar question but it did not help as I want to automate all this and if possible stay in sync with the official nopCommerce build process:

[How to publish NopCommerce and NopCommerce admin website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607629/how-to-publish-nopcommerce-and-nopcommerce-admin-website)

Comment: Newer versions of NopCommerce no longer use that janky custom build process, and use a standard Build & Package/Publish operation. However, even with the older version, you should be able to somehow tell your build server to run Nop's build batch file, and then capture the output and deploy using MSDeploy. I don't know much about TFS builds, but any half-way decent build agent should allow you to perform these operations via a command line build definition. That being said, I don't consider TFS to be half-way decent at anything, so...

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the nopCommerce source code
2. Open it with Visual Studio
3. Add a new Azure Cloud Service
4. Open the Azure Cloud service project
5. Select the Roles folder and right click to open up menu
6. Select 'Add web role project in solution'
7. Go through the wizard to Publish to Azure (make sure you select 'Enable Remote Desktop')

After publishing you can't load any plugins. This is due to the fact that nopCommerce runs under the NetworkService account and that account doesn't have sufficient permissions. You can remote to the server and change the application pool identity to LocalSystem to test if it works as expected. After testing make sure to assign another identity with just sufficient permissions.